# How to use While activity and Replicator Activity on Shareponit Workflows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, workflow-foundation, sharepoint-workflow

I have developed a document approval workflow which I needed to use the Replicator Activity to solve the need for many people who can elaborate, review and Approve a document.

The workflow is performed on a sequence model as the state machine will not let me use the Replicator Activity.

For an idea of ​​the workflow I follow [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh128696.aspx).

The problem is that I can't restart the workflow if someone rejects the document.

I was doing some tests using the `While Activity` to solve the problem but tasks are empty (Asigando to: is empty, title: is empty) for some issue generates error to the Replicator Activity.

Is there a known solution to this problem? or that otherwise could make the restart of my workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an additional custom activity and put the contents of the replicator in the activity and add the activity to the replicator. When you are putting tasks directly in the replicator activity, they won't work somehow because they are having same tokens.

Also make sure you give different tasks different ids and tokens.

Comment: I will comment for any news

Comment: I follow this example, I think is the same you saying http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh128696.aspx, and works fine until I try to put all the REPLICATOR ACTIVITY (that contains a custom activity) on a WHILE ACTIVITY, I need that because workflow must restart when the user reject the document.

Comment: or if there another way to do this ??

Comment: If you are putting only the replicator activity (with its contents) that shouldn't be a problem. but if there are other activities in the while loop, you should add all the activities inside while activity, along with the replicator, inside a sequence activity, and then put the sequence activity inside while loop. This is because while activity can only have 1 activity inside itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Paiman,

I appreciate your help.

I comment you that to provide a solution to my problem, I use the workflow of state machines and discard the initial idea of using Replicator Activity.

For the problem of assigning more than one task in the same state, ie if there is more than one user for the same state that it is for example the "revision of the document". for the first user after complete review task sends flow to the next state would be "document approval" before create a task to approval wonder if there is more than one user to the "state review" and if is true workflow return to the previous state which would be the Revision and create the new task and change the following user assign to review.